# Poor video quality in Ubuntu!

Tags: 16.04, drivers, graphics, video, intel

[img 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLTb5.jpg)

[img 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4r0vW.jpg)

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 recently and noticed that the video quality in Ubuntu is poor compared to Windows 10.I have no issues on Linux Mint but I don't like the windows xp layout of LM.I have attached the images to help you identify the problem.(Even though the video is in HD , you can see the lines.I have an Intel HD 4400 graphics card and AMD Radeon M5 3300.
Please help asap!!